# jquery ui tabs multiple calls to tabs()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page where I put my tab content into a div.

This work fine and I can see the tabs.

Later, an event occurs (like selecting a combo box value) and I want to change to another set of tab.

I basically did:

```
('#divId').empty();
someData.appendTo("#divId");
$("#divId").tabs();
```

Here is the problem, this 2nd call show me a list:
. tabName1
. tabName2
..... etc

Any idea what's going on, seems like the call to .tabs() work only once when I first load the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your problem?

Comment: I encountered similar issue with jQuery UI - TABS widget. Apparently there was nothing wrong with my `someData`, instead I always love to use default `element.innerHTML = ""` instead of using any extra function like `empty()`. I got the issue resolved by using `jQuery(element).tabs("destroy")` prior to creation. Make sure to keep the **destroy** call conditional or in a try catch block to avoid failures in case of not initialized tabs call to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `someData`, it might contain invalid html that cannot handled when you call the jquery tabs() method again.

One way to do it is:

```
console.log(someData);
```

Then if you're using chrome, hit F12 then click on "Console".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#detailUL").append("<li><a href='#tabs3-"+id+"'>Desc No "+m+"</a></li>");     // desc

$("#details").append("<div id='tabs3-"+id+"' class='it_detail'>"+copy+"</div>"); // detail


$("#detailPanel").tabs("refresh");
```